# Creating a comma delimited file from a very messy text file

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create a comma delimited file from a very messy text file. I have looked at some of the questions posted on here that may have been related, but so far nothing is working.

Here is a very small piece of the file:

1  1

E  1  1

2  2

1

2

E  2  2

3  3

```
   7        C1
```

E  3  3

4  4

```
   7        C1
```

E  4  4

5  5

3

E  5  5

6  6

E  6  6

7  7

E  7  7

8  8

3

E  8  8

9  9

E  9  9

10  10

E  10  10

Any suggestions would be really appreciated. Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: How do you wish to comma-separate the above text ? after every space/tab (or) after every line ?

Comment: What did you try so far? Look at strip() and split() methods for strings.

Comment: I have tried them for strings. I need to know how to read from this file and create a comma delimited file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the issue that you are trying to work both at the line level and the "chunk" level at the same time?

str.split() deals with space(s) and tab(s) by default already:

```
lines = open('infile.txt').readlines()
# split each line based on tabs and spaces
lines = [ x.split() for x in lines ]
# remove empty fields (assuming you want to)
lines = [ x for x in lines if len(x) > 0 ]
# transform your lists (lines) into coma separated strings
lines = [ ','.join(x) for x in lines ]
# separate lines with \n for writelines
lines = [ x + '\n' for x in lines ]
open('outfile.txt', 'w').writelines(lines)
```

Of course you can combine a few of these list comprehensions, I kept them separate for clarity.